# Problem in accessing JBoss and other Repositories through Nexus Repository Manager

Tags: maven, repository, nexus

We are using Nexus Repository Manager as our Corporate Repository Manager. The nexus repository manager was linked to JBoss Repository with following remote url.

https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/ Today when I checked the nexus, i saw following message for JBoss In Service - Remote automatically blocked and unavailable.

This message generally comes when your firewall is not allowing you to access the JBoss url. But the nexus is able to access maven central repository, which indirectly tells that there is no problem in the Proxy.

The same message is also shown for following urls
Name URL Type/Policy
java.net - Maven 2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2/) proxy/Release
java.net-m1 (http://download.java.net/maven/1/) proxy/Release
Apache Snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/) proxy/Snapshot

Please reply if any one has idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

According to this blog post

http://www.sonatype.com/people/2011/09/8942/

you no longer need to worry about having the JBoss repo referenced because all JBoss artifacts have been cleaned up and migrated to Maven Central.

Java.net used to be unreliable and had issues, which would cause the same issue. Should be much better now since it runs on Nexus as well.